# Importing css into Meteor project results in SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: css, meteor

**EDIT: I solved this issue.

For imports to work with Meteor, you have to put your code in an /imports/ directory. Here's the [official guide](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) on structuring your app. It's odd because I was importing and exporting most things just fine without using their recommended file structure. It was only css imports that were not working.**

Whenever a import css from an npm package, I get the following error:

```
W20161023-13:23:17.701(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/mattmacpherson/Code/project/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:3
W20161023-13:23:17.701(-4)? (STDERR) .CodeMirror {
W20161023-13:23:17.701(-4)? (STDERR) ^        
W20161023-13:23:17.702(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20161023-13:23:17.702(-4)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
W20161023-13:23:17.703(-4)? (STDERR)     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20161023-13:23:17.703(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
W20161023-13:23:17.704(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
W20161023-13:23:17.704(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
W20161023-13:23:17.704(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.load (/Users/mattmacpherson/.meteor/packages/babel-compiler/.6.9.1_1.15j1r1l++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
W20161023-13:23:17.704(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
W20161023-13:23:17.704(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
W20161023-13:23:17.705(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
W20161023-13:23:17.705(-4)? (STDERR)     at npmRequire (/Users/mattmacpherson/Code/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm-require.js:129:10)
W20161023-13:23:17.705(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.useNode (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:69:1)
```

The example above is when importing codemirror's css but I also get the same error with many other packages, including react-s-alert and medium-draft.

Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-es2015",
    "babel-preset-react",
    "babel-preset-stage-2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Having exact same issue

Comment: I figured this issue out. For imports to work with Meteor, you have to put your code in a /imports/ directory. Here the [official guide](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) on structuring your app. It's odd because I was importing and exporting most things just fine without using their recommended file structure. It was only css imports that were not working.

Comment: I'm already using their file structure @methodx and still having this issue, how did you solve importing CSS files ?